# Typeof arguments object in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I basically have this:

```
function foo(){

 // literally pass the arguments object into the pragmatik.parse method
 // the purpose of pragmatik.parse is to handle more complex variadic functions

 const [a,b,c,d,e] = pragmatik.parse(arguments);

 // now we have the correct arguments in the expected location, using array destructuring


}
```

so we have the `pragmatik.parse` method:

```
function parse(args){

   // return parsed arguments

}
```

now I want to use TypeScript to define types, all I know is that arguments is an Object:

```
function parse(args: Object){


}
```

so my question is: does TypeScript give a definition or type for an `arguments` object in JS? Sorry this is a bit meta, but please bear with me, what I am asking about is sane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Webstorm IDE suggests that this might be `IArguments`, which is provided by: `lib/es6/d.ts`, which is somewhere out there. Maybe someone can verify this is correct, but I am fairly certain.

So the answer would be:

```
function parse(args: IArguments){


}
```

and the full signature would be:

```
function parse(args: IArguments) : Array<any> {


}
```

since the parse method returns a generic array

Answer (score 1):

You can pick exact type of arguments with [tsargs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsargs) package from npm

Eg:

```
import { ArgsN } from 'tsargs';

function foo(a: boolean, b: number, c: string) {}
const argsABC: ArgsN<typeof foo> = [ true, 123, 'Hello' ];
```

In your case:

```
import { ArgsN } from 'tsargs';

function parse<T extends (...args: any[]) => any>(args: IArguments): ArgsN<T> {
    // return parsed arguments
}

// ...

const args = parse<typeof foo>(arguments);
// args -> [ boolean, number, string ];
```